# PHPH | How to escape this long string with regex?

Tags: php, regex, string, escaping

Is there anyone who works with regexes in PHP and knows how to escape them well? I've tried writing my first regex today, and I'm failing to escape it correctly.

This is the string that I want to select (single string inside the input string):

```
$(this).load(urlStr, data, function (response, innerstatus, xhr) {
                    status = innerstatus;
                    pb.hide();
                    sbmt_btn.show();
                    if (status == "error") {
                        var msg = "Sorry but there was an error: ";
                        $(this).html(msg + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);
                    }
                    if ($('#NoMoreSearchForYou').get(0)) {
                        $('.ui-dialog-buttonset').hide();
                    }
                    else if ($('#MoreSearchForYou').length > 0) {
                        $('.ui-dialog-buttonset').show();
                    }
                    else {
                        $('.ui-dialog-buttonset').hide();
                    }
                });
```

This is the regex string I used - tested in (see a live demo): http://regexr.com/3e0qv

```
/\$\(this.+[\s\S]*hide\(\);[\s\S]{49};/m
```

Characters that are a part of the target string:

```
), $, hide, (, ), ;
```

And an explanation to how they work would also help a lot.

`preg_quote` and hand-made escaping didn't work for me.
I'd appreciate help a lot! I'm stuck on this.

Comment: What is an example of something you want it to match? There's no syntax errors, so I'm not sure what you're stuck on.

Comment: Give an example string and the expected output.

Comment: Use `'~\$\(this[\s\S]*hide\(\);[\s\S]{49};~m'`

Comment: Thanks for the replies, guys.

I added the input and expected output strings.

Comment: Why should you catch only 49 characters of class `[\s\S]`? What is the purpose?

Comment: And you should know there is no semi-colon after engine matches that 49 characters. That's why you get no result.

Comment: I've got a certain amount of spaces there, which look like new lines, but for some reasons are spaces, and I wasn't able to do [\s\S]* and then a word at the end of the string (so it'd be any number of spaces, and then ending with that word).

So I just counted the number of spaces, and it's 49.

You can test the regex I wrote in http://regexr.com and see for yourself. It works.

Comment: Please make your live demo and put the link in your question. Also clearly show us which part of that input string is in your favor.

Comment: I added a link to a live demo.

Like I said, the input string I gave here is exactly what I want to select, out of a bigger input string. I just didn't get the rest of the input string, because the rest doesn't matter.

You can see in the live demo it being selected with the regex I made (the same one I posted here).

Comment: The input string provided in live demo is slightly different from the one you posted in your question. Also your RegEx in your question has a `\m` part which is not exactly clear what you mean by that and last thing is that now what is your real question if it works?

Comment: About the `\m` - I wrote the flag by hand, and I made a mistake. It was supposed to be `/m`.

About the question - it works in RegExr. But it doesn't work in my own code.

I copied my input string and pasted it into RegExr, and made the regular expression there, and it worked.

But when I did `$regex_result = preg_match($regex, $response, $matches)[0]);` and then `var_dump($regex_result)`, it printed "NULL".

Comment: Right way is doing it this way: `preg_match($regex, $response, $matches); var_dump($matches[0]);` [Live demo](https://3v4l.org/fKIqa)

Comment: revo, I took your code, and it doesn't work.
This is literally all that there is, one-to-one to yours.

Is there a chance that there's library/extension PHP setting problem? That regex isn't activated or something?

Edit: It is enabled. I just checked phpinfo(). I don't know why it doesn't work for me. I literally copied your code and pasted it.

Comment: Did you copy code from URL I have provided? If yes then it should work. You are simply running a simple regex by that means.

Comment: I copied it from the live demo you linked to.


See what I've done [here](http://image.prntscr.com/image/d498412b29e8480db33bf30f68888dfb.png)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120911/discussion-between-gal-grunfeld-and-revo).